# How to get the id when is clicked and remove that? Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web

Here is my code...I try to put event listener but the console says:

> markers.addListener is not a function

Here is my code.....https://jsfiddle.net/1LwLczgr/1/

```
//The problem :(
markers.addListener('click', function() {
      var marker = this;
      alert(this.id+"alasddsasdkasdl");
});



<!--My API-->
<script async defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBZiX9quA0AJiAFuoxrogRYObImmbCa-6g&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry,places&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: typo in code- it is `addEventListener`...

Comment: the same...addEventListener is not a function

Comment: There are javascript errors in your fiddle (`Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function`, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`)

Comment: yes problem of the API (i dont know how to put script tag in jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add Google Maps click listeners to a Google Maps objects that support click events (like a [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker).  `markers` is not a [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker), it is an `Array`.  `Array`s don't have the method `.addListener`.

One option would be to add the click listener to the marker when you create it:

```
// Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    id:count,
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    var marker = this;
    alert(this.id+"alasddsasdkasdl");
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  countmarkers ++;
  count ++;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! and then for delete that only.... setmap markers[id].setMap(null)?

Answer (score 1):

**markers** is an Array object. 
Can't we do:

```
$.each(markers, function(index, value) {
// Add listener here? 
});
```

Reference: 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Or in plain JavaScript:

```
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
{
// Add listener here? 
}
```

Edit - to the question - and then inside DeleteMarkers()'s function?

- Remove listener via looping
- Clear the array

Wouldn't that help? Please give it a try and let us know the result.

Comment: and then inside DeleteMarkers()'s function?

Comment: I put markers.addEventListener with each jquery's function out of initMap and the console doesn't tell me that there is something wrong but i don't get any alert of the id!!

Comment: As mentioned by @geocodezip we cannot do `markers.addEventListener` as **markers** is an Array object; We should be dealing with an element in that array, which is - **google.maps.Marker**. You can do this by looping the array **markers**

Comment: You can do this by looping the array **markers**, and set/reset the implementation you want on them. 

Here the issue is that - you were dealing with an **Array** object instead of treating the array members.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `addListener()` type `addEventListener()`.

Comment: the same...addEventListener is not a function

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me after fixing few things. The script tag needs to be closed. The addListener was required on markers[0] (not on the markers array itself). I moved the initMap function so that it doesn't complain. I uncommented the event listener. It worked.

Comment: i dont understand....The addListener was required on markers[0] (not on the markers array itself).....In the other hand, thanks but i had resolved this post thanks  to @geocodezip

Comment: @I looked at @geocodezip's code. He creates marker, adds listener to it, and then pushes the marker into an array. OTOH, your code was creating a marker, pushing the marker into an array, and then adding listener to the array object itself.